# Xcode 9 GM seed Simulator Screen Artefacts

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, beta

I have simulator screen problems, after installment of last beta, it's happen randomly, when i build any project, usually on 3-4 time, when i hit play. Have to quit Simulator Application, and start it again.

Anyone have same issue ?

Screenshot:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWyee.png]

Comment: Have the same. Not this bad but the same. Try hitting some buttons as they are still functional and when screen is redrawn these tend to disappear. The more interesting thing with xcode 9 and ios11 is that some of my ibactions stopped working with no apparent reason. Any clues?

Comment: @RaimundasSakalauskas try to check your outlet connections, i noticed that some of my outlets randomly disconnected for no reason

Comment: @DavidDavidoff What version of Xcode 9 are you using? If this is the GM then please file bug at https://bugreport.apple.com and attach the output of `xcrun simctl diagnose` and `sudo sysdiagnose -q` so we can debug.

Comment: Also, as a workaround, you can try using a different renderer by running `defaults write http://com.apple .CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint 3` (1=Metal, 3=OpenGL).

Comment: I updated today to Xcode 9 and I am still having this issue.

Comment: Using OpenGL seems to have fixed it for me

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia answer helps me too. (Note: `http://` can be skipped). Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, odd.  It looks like StackOverflow formatting messed that up.  Sorry I didn't notice that earlier... unfortunately, the comment isn't editable to fix it. =/

Comment: FramebufferRendererHint 2 worked for me! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Metal is the default renderer for the new simulator and some of the older Apple devices do not support it :

[Mac computers that support Metal](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205073)

For example, I have a mid 2011 Mac-mini and had to switch it to OpenGL to get the simulator working (as suggested by @Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia)