# What causes visual glitches with Xcode 9's iOS Simulator and how can I fix them?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When running applications on the simulator with Xcode 9, I regularly experience a handful of visual glitches, which include **red device identifier labels** and content that **duplicates itself** and **leaves pixel mess after it moves**. I did not have these issues with Xcode 8.

[image: red device identifier label]

[image: messy content]

These occur regardless of the OS of the simulator, I replicated the issue with iOS 11 and 10.

This might be unrelated, but I use a legacy version of iClipboard (6.0.0) and a similar glitch persists inside the search bar sometimes.

[image: iClipboard - glitch in search bar]

What causes these glitches and what can I do to fix them?

Comment: Are you using macOS High Sierra? Apple has rewritten the Window Manager for the OS and this is supposedly causing these glitches. Maybe that's the issue here. I don't know if there is any fix yet. If the glitches are related to macOS High Sierra, downgrading to macOS Sierra would be one option (though not very efficient).

Comment: Step one: file a bug report with Apple!

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223236

Comment: @Pang It is somewhat related, but the artifacts are different.

Comment: I've seen this as well - also filed a bug with Apple. Hopefully goes away soon

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing macOS High Sierra latest version (10.13.4 (17E202)) will solve this issue, i had similar issue with my Mac-book Pro.

Please be sure you are hard formatting and then re-installing the fresh OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the last Xcode. Xcode 11.5.0 is the latest current stable version.